# vimgrep can not find a pattern in specified directory

Tags: search, vim-windows

I have encountered very strange problem using vimgrep command. I try to find a match in all the files in all subdirs of a specified directory:

```
:vimgrep /word_I_search/ path\to\my\dir\**\*
```

(there are backslashes in path because I am on Windows). Command reports:

```
E480: No match: word_I_search
```

But I know there are matches! And if I do not search in subdirs or if I start searching one level higher everything is ok. Following commands successfully find what I want:

```
:vimgrep /word_I_search/ path\to\my\dir\*
:vimgrep /word_I_search/ path\to\my\**\*
```

I have never encountered this problem on my Linux machine and do not know where to start troubleshooting it. Any ideas? Please help.

UPDATE:

command works as expected if I use less backslashes. Following commands work as expected:

```
:vimgrep /word_I_search/ path/to/my/dir/**/*
:vimgrep /word_I_search/ path\to\my\dir\**/*
```

Comment: You don't need to use backslashes.

Comment: Thanks, @romani! The problem is that slashes are automatically replaced by backslashes when I press <tab> to autocomplete path. But looks like I found workaround.

Answer (score 2):

So to conclude, one has to do:

```
 :vimgrep /text/ path_to_dir/* path_to_dir/**/*
```

if he wants to include the dir.

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case, I was forgetting to add the trailing slash after `/text` before specifying the path to search for this text in.

Answer (score 1):

`**` matches only directories as you can read in http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#file-searching, but obviously **at least 1 subdirectory** if you are using backslashes in your path.
I.e. `**` matches not *0..n* but *1..n* subdirectories. (Again) this is true only when you are using backslashes in your search path.

Comment: I think in the context of `vimgrep` this is not true. See the linked documentation. It talks about a few functionalities and adds: "Other commands use |wildcards|
which is slightly different.". Also: I couldn't reproduce the problem on Windows7 with Vim 8.1.751.

Comment: I wrote _obviously_ in the anser above because I could reproduce this issue on Win10 with a x64 build of Vim 8.0 (2016 Sep 12). After some testing, I concluded that it matters if you use forward- or backslashes and if you use \, `vimgrep` needs to match at least one subdirectory.

Comment: @sachint The important part is the first 2 sentences. Vimgrep uses [wildcards](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#wildcards), not [file-searching](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#file-searching).